# Handling sequential downloads with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have a data fetch task that I want to perform on a background thread but need to make additional calls after getting a response in the `completionBlock`.

For example:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:requestURL completionHandler:completionBlock] resume];
```

After the task successfully fetches the data and calls `completionBlock` I want to download say an additional 10 resources from `NSURL` that are part of the data `completionBlock` gets.

Would it be better to call `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` again in the block per request  or make blocking network calls in a loop in the `completionBlock`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just make the additional calls within the `completionBlock`. But the requests should not be "blocking", but rather you'd just initiate additional asynchronous requests for the additional data. You want them to operate concurrently with respect to each other, if your model supports that. You pay a significant performance penalty if you issue those subsequent requests sequentially versus concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but to follow up further if I went the route you mentioned and wanted to have certain events happen say when half the resources are downloaded and then again when all resources are downloaded would I just use this method with a counter variable that the other Async blocks increment as they finish?

Comment: Yep. Just make sure this counter is thread safe (e.g. dispatch the counter logic to serial queue, such as main queue, or use lock or `@synchronized` block).